# Navbar interfering with content

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm currently working on my first website, also I'm still new to HTML and CSS, so sorry if the code is a bit "sloppy". Anyways I made a navbar that works in the home page ( it has an image background ). I found online "about" page code that I found helpful, so I used it, the problem it that the navbar interfers with it and makes it weird.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);

}
.header ul{
    text-align: center;
}
.header ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.header ul li a{
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:white;
    font-size: 100%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 25px;
    transition: width .3s;
}
.about{
    background: url("/images/Industrial2.jpg") no-repeat left;
    background-size: 55%;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 100px 0;
}
.inner-section{
    width: 55%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    padding: 140px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.inner-section h1{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.text{
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #545454;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.skills button{
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #00999c;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.skills button:hover{
    transition: 1s;
    background-color: #ecf5f5;
    color: #00999c;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1200px){
    .inner-section{
        padding: 80px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
    .about{
        background-size: 100%;
        padding: 100px 40px;
    }
    .inner-section{
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    .about{
        padding: 0;
    }
    .inner-section{
        padding: 60px;
    }
    .skills button{
        font-size: 19px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 160px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>About</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    
</head>
<div class="header"></div>
<body>
    <div class="about">
        <div class="inner-section">
            <div class="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <h1>About Us</h1>
            <p class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Doloribus velit ducimus, enim inventore earum, eligendi
                nostrum pariatur necessitatibus eius dicta a voluptates sit
                deleniti autem error eos totam
                nisi neque voluptates sit deleniti autem error eos totam nisi neque.
            </p>
            <div class="skills">
                <button>Contact Us</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKKkO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Sry for not giving you a *direct* answer, but here's a tip:
Try using any framework (like [MDP](https://todoapp.rf.gd/framework/beta/#), I'm the author of the framework) or bootstrap for your project.
If you use it, I suggest you to use grid to make your website look better

EDIT: Ok! Here is a website which is almost like which you need
https://todoapp.rf.gd/framework/beta/templates/10298/#

Comment: I mainly don’t want to use anything besides HTML and CSS, I’m still new to web development, thats why.

Comment: Oh, No problem... MDP is plain HTML and CSS. JS is optional

Comment: Did you check out the example website I made for you?

Comment: I just did, sorry about not seeing it except now. The problem is I'm not using buttons, is it okay?

Comment: It's okay. You can remove and add whatever you want to

Comment: And if you want to use my framework, you'll need to download the CSS file here: https://todoapp.rf.gd/framework/beta/css/style.css

Comment: Thank you Manu! I'll try implementing some of the code in my code, hopefully someone else steps in and show me what I should edit in my code. Again I appreciate your help :) I'll try to learn MDP if its only plain HTML and CSS

Comment: Sure! The documentation is here: http://todoapp.rf.gd/framework/beta

Comment: This will probably very useful especially in the future, or even in the case I'm stuck in. Thank you Manu!